# Defining and reading a nullable date column in Slick 3.x

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I have a table with a column type date. This column accepts null values, therefore, I declared it as an Option (see field `perDate` below). The issue is that apparently the implicit conversion from/to `java.time.LocalDate`/`java.sql.Date` is incorrect as reading from this table when `perDate` is null fails with the error:

```
slick.SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column <computed>
```

This is the Slick table definition, including the implicit function:

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate

class FormulaDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Formula](tag, "formulas") {

  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def descrip = column[Option[String]]("descrip")
  def formula = column[Option[String]]("formula")
  def notes = column[Option[String]]("notes")
  def periodicity = column[Int]("periodicity")
  def perDate = column[Option[LocalDate]]("per_date")(localDateColumnType)

  def * = (sk, name, descrip, formula, notes, periodicity, perDate) <> 
       ((Formula.apply _).tupled, Formula.unapply)


  implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Option[LocalDate], Date](
     {
        case Some(localDate) => Date.valueOf(localDate)
        case None => null
     },{
        sqlDate => if (sqlDate != null) Some(sqlDate.toLocalDate) else None
     }
  )

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually your `implicit conversion` from/to `java.time.LocalDate/java.sql.Date` is not incorrect.

I have faced the same error, and doing some research I found that the Node created by the Slick SQL Compiler is actually of type `MappedJdbcType[Scala.Option -> LocalDate]`, and not `Option[LocalDate]`.

That is the reason why when the mapping compiler create the column converter for your ***def perDate*** it is creating a ***Base*** `ResultConverter`and not a ***Option*** `ResultConverter`

Here is the `Slick code` for the base converter:

```
def base[T](ti: JdbcType[T], name: String, idx: Int) = (ti.scalaType match {
    case ScalaBaseType.byteType => new BaseResultConverter[Byte](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Byte]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.shortType => new BaseResultConverter[Short](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Short]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.intType => new BaseResultConverter[Int](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Int]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.longType => new BaseResultConverter[Long](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Long]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.charType => new BaseResultConverter[Char](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Char]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.floatType => new BaseResultConverter[Float](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Float]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.doubleType => new BaseResultConverter[Double](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Double]], name, idx)
    case ScalaBaseType.booleanType => new BaseResultConverter[Boolean](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[Boolean]], name, idx)
    case _ => new BaseResultConverter[T](ti.asInstanceOf[JdbcType[T]], name, idx) {
      override def read(pr: ResultSet) = {
        val v = ti.getValue(pr, idx)
        if(v.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] eq null) throw new SlickException("Read NULL value ("+v+") for ResultSet column "+name)
        v
      }
    }
  }).asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, T]]
```

Unfortunately I have no solution for this problem, what I suggest as a workaround, is to map your *perDate* property as follows:

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate

class FormulaDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Formula](tag, "formulas") {

  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def descrip = column[Option[String]]("descrip")
  def formula = column[Option[String]]("formula")
  def notes = column[Option[String]]("notes")
  def periodicity = column[Int]("periodicity")
  def perDate = column[Option[Date]]("per_date")

  def toLocalDate(time : Option[Date]) : Option[LocalDate] = time.map(t => t.toLocalDate))  
  def toSQLDate(localDate : Option[LocalDate]) : Option[Date] = localDate.map(localDate => Date.valueOf(localDate)))  


  private type FormulaEntityTupleType = (Int, String, Option[String], Option[String], Option[String], Int, Option[Date])

  private val formulaShapedValue = (sk, name, descrip, formula, notes, periodicity, perDate).shaped[FormulaEntityTupleType]

  private val toFormulaRow: (FormulaEntityTupleType => Formula) = { formulaTuple => {
      Formula(formulaTuple._1, formulaTuple._2, formulaTuple._3, formulaTuple._4, formulaTuple._5, formulaTuple._6, toLocalDate(formulaTuple._7))
     }
  }

  private val toFormulaTuple: (Formula => Option[FormulaEntityTupleType]) = { formulaRow =>
   Some((formulaRow.sk, formulaRow.name, formulaRow.descrip, formulaRow.formula, formulaRow.notes, formulaRow.periodicity, toSQLDate(formulaRow.perDate)))
  }

  def * = formulaShapedValue <> (toFormulaRow, toFormulaTuple)
```

Hopefully the answer comes not too late.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my workaround was to define a default value for the date, so it's never null

Comment: Yes, that works too when you have access to your DB definition, which is your case. On my case I could not modify the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that your'e returning `null` from your mapping function instead of `None`.

Try rewriting your mapping function as a function from `LocalDate` to `Date`:

```scala
implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
  {
    localDate => Date.valueOf(localDate)
  },{
    sqlDate => sqlDate.toLocalDate
  }
)
```

Alternately, mapping from `Option[LocalDate]` to `Option[Date]` should work:

```scala
implicit val localDateColumnType =
  MappedColumnType.base[Option[LocalDate], Option[Date]](
    {
      localDateOption => localDateOption.map(Date.valueOf)
    },{
      sqlDateOption => sqlDateOption.map(_.toLocalDate)
    }
  )
```

Comment: how to map from `Option[LocalDate]` to `Option[date]` ? Since the column is defined as `column[Option[LocalDate]]` I cannot map from LocalDate to Date.

Comment: Also, in your function the fields `localDate` and `sqlDate` are undefined

Comment: I fixed the function literals, and added an option mapping example.

Comment: I'm getting a compilation error when I try to use the option mapping example: `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type slick.driver.MySQLDriver.BaseColumnType[Option[java.sql.Date]]` is it OK to have an Option of a java type?